# My Windows XP always boots into chkdisk

Tags: windows-xp

My Windows XP will not boot. I keep getting this message over and over – once it checks the dics it just reloads and does the same thing again.

The type of the file system is NTFS. Volume label is data.
 One of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. you may cancel the disc check, but is strongly recommended that you continue.
 Windows will now check the disc
 chkdsk is veryifying files stage one of three
 chkdsk is verifying indexes
 chkdsk is verifying security

Comment: @Tog Yes it is a duplicate to the point that He posted that question.

Answer (score 0):

Skip disk C: autocheck:

```
CHKNTFS /X C:
```

or, edit registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet
BootExecute REG_MULTI_SZ autocheck autochk /k:C *
```

If there are other logical partitions drives, just list them on, for example:

```
CHKNTFS /X C: D: I: N: O: P:
```

or, edit registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet
BootExecute REG_MULTI_SZ autocheck autochk /k:C /k:D /k:I /k:N /k:O /k:P *
```

If you not may boot, use any liveCD or Windows 7 boot CD, mount registry and edit key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00x\Control\Session Manager
BootExecute REG_MULTI_SZ
```

Run `cmd` at Windows 7 boot CD: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>