# How do I stop a CHKDSK infinite loop?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, chkdsk, safe-mode, infinite-loop

I started up my Windows XP box last weekend after it had been off for quiet a while, at least a few months. At first, when I started it up I received a blue screen with no message, and it restarted. I then selected `Last known good configuration`, and XP started booting up. Awesome! But wait, it tells me that it has to run a CHKDSK...

I can wait. So I do, it goes through the CHKDSK, but then it restarts, and what does it ask for on the next restart? Another CHKDSK. So I try to skip the CHKDSK this time, and what happens? **I cannot press a key to skip the CHKDSK.** So right now I'm stuck in an infinite loop of CHKDSKs and unable to get into XP. I've tried all the variations of Safe Mode, disabling restart on system failure (maybe I was missing a blue screen after the CHKDSK...). But no, nothing.

I was able to get into the recovery console, but honestly I have no idea what to do now that I'm there. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is already a answer located on this very website that goes into detail on how to disable the authomatic chkdsk on a volume.

Comment: Hold on, I forgot a very valuable piece of information. I cannot press a key to skip the CHKDSK.

Comment: My comment remains the same. You have to modify a registry key that is causing this. Of course the drive itself is failing. Windows knows this command needs to be ran. You should replace the drive in question.  http://superuser.com/questions/597019/my-windows-xp-always-boots-into-chkdisk/597069#597069

Comment: @NobleUplift is CHKDSK repairing files? If so this can be expected behavior as Windows may need to restart to continue the CHKDSK, How many times has this happened?

Comment: I made the mistake of using Intel Fake RAID to create a RAID-1 array. If I do have to reinstall, no way I'm doing that again. Also, the CHKDSK comes back 100% clean, just as every one before it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few hacks to stop Windows from doing this, [such as disabling CHKDSK at boot](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643) and renaming chkdsk.exe to chkdsk1.exe, or just replacing chkdsk.exe with an empty, read-only file. Of course, none of these worked.

The problem was the way that Windows read my RAID array at boot. I had an [issue with the installation of the RAID driver](https://superuser.com/questions/562845/how-do-i-fix-a-windows-xp-bootloader-error-when-bootcfg-fixboot-and-fixmbr-do), and somehow the RAID signature on the hard drives was triggering the CHKDSK on every boot. [These Intel chipsets](https://superuser.com/questions/563421/what-is-the-difference-between-intel-ich7r-dh-ich7mdh-and-express-chipset) are such a hassle they aren't worth using in the slightest.

When I deleted the RAID array, I was able to boot into Windows XP no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you say you had a bluescreen i would recommend using the hirens cd.
Use the bluescreenviewer because maybe there is a hardware error.
If there is not i would back-up all the files you need and install windows again.

I hope you had something to this.

Amin

Comment: I'll try it out next chance I get. You should consider registering so that you keep your reputation if I upvote/accept your answer.

Comment: He said there was no blue screen...

Comment: @TheX - **"I received a blue screen ..."** granted its not clear if the author means something other than a `BSoD`

Comment: I had _one_ blue screen to begin with, but I have not received a blue screen since this infinite loop began.

Comment: I think I would start with a Disc Scan utility and check for bad sectors, A RAM check, with memtest86+ (1 to 2 passes) to see if you have a bad RAM card... if none of these show any errors then I would boot with my Windows disc, open the command prompt (not sure exactly how to do this on XP, it has been a long time, but you should be able to find it on the internet) and run a sfc /scannow to see if there are any missing or corrupt system files...

Comment: @NobleUplift - Your system actually is crashing thus the infinite reboot. Your hdd needs to be replaced. This infinite reboot problem was likely caused by a corrupt system file or required drive being deleted by chkdsk.

Comment: I'll see if I can touch the system with an Ubuntu Live disk. That has memtest on it and I might be able to read the hard drive.